# How to add multiple objects (buttons) to extension area of the table control in SAPUI5

Tags: layout, sapui5

This is my code:

```
 var oTableRes = new sap.ui.table.Table({
        //   title: "Employee Details", 
        id: "resultsTable",
        visibleRowCount: 10,
        selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
        navigationMode: sap.ui.table.NavigationMode.Paginator, //Paginator or Scrollbar
        fixedColumnCount: 3, // Freezes the number of columns
        enableColumnReordering: true, // Allows you to drag and drop the column and reorder the position of the column
        width: "650px", // width of the table
        height: "400px",
        extension: [
            new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                text: "",
                id: "addExamResult",
                press: oController.addExam
            }),
            new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                text: "Delete exam result",
                id: "delExamResult",
                press: oController.deleteExam
            })
        ],
        rowSelectionChange: oController.onRowSelectExam
    });
```

This is my code. This produces two buttons as desired, in the extension area. However, each item added to the extension area goes to a new line. How to make them stay in one row? (I tried creating cells, then matrix layout, creating the row with two cells (one for each button), and adding layout into extension area but I got an error:

> Uncaught Error: "Element sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutRow#__row0" is not valid for aggregation "extension" of Element sap.ui.table.Table#resultsTable

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have added `MatrixLayoutRow` in the extension, but you should have added `MatrixLayout` instead (with can have one or more `MatrixLayoutRow`s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the extension section expects a control this should work

```
extension : [ new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
            busy : false, // boolean
            busyIndicatorDelay : 1000, // int
            visible : true, // boolean
            allowWrapping : false, // boolean
            tooltip : undefined, // sap.ui.core.TooltipBase

            content : [ new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                text : "Button1",
                id : "addExamResult",

            }), new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                text : "Delete exam result",
                id : "delExamResult",

            }) ]
        // sap.ui.core.Control
        }) ]
```

Does this fit your requirement? 
Adding [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/doweweboji/edit?html,output)